# Prove that there exists 5 consecutive numbers, each of which is divisible by a cube of a positive integer greater than 1.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have trouble even starting on the question because I cannot create any relationships between those 5 numbers.

Comment: Hint: use the Chinese remainder theorem to build an example.

Comment: @lulu But then I would be working with multiple variables. How would I able to define a relationship if I am not given a number for a congruence?

Comment: To make the suggestion more precise: use CRT to find $n$ such that $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2^3}$, $n \equiv -1 \pmod{3^3}$, $n \equiv -2 \pmod{5^3}$, $n \equiv -3 \pmod{7^3}$, $n \equiv -4 \pmod{11^3}$.

Comment: Solve $n\equiv 0 \pmod {2^3}$, $n\equiv 1 \pmod {3^3}$, $n\equiv 2\pmod {5^3}$....